# Activity tab disappeared on app store connect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Why does the *Activity* tab disappears on the app store connect web sometimes?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

We can see the build info from TestFlight tab.
Select any build from TestFlight and then select Build Metadata tab. [image]

Comment: Also, the "Processing" status, previously displayed in the Activity tab, is now directly shown in the iOS Builds list on the Testflight tab

Comment: I've received email from apple developer support.

```
I'm with Apple Developer Program Support. I’m following up with you regarding your recent email.

I understand you are unable to locate the Activity tab in App Store Connect. I can certainly look into this for you.

After researching your request, it looks like the Activity tab has merged with the TestFlight tab in App Store Connect. You can now see your build metadata under the TestFlight tab under your app record.
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also access the tab by:

appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps/*your-app-id-her*e/recent/activity/ios/builds?m=

reference: [Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/669024)

P.S. The link trick works at the moment, but might not be permanent.

Comment: now, that link will not work. it will redirect to main page.

Comment: I think it's not working anymore... at least not for me :(

Answer (score 0):

The Tab has moved recently (it's not a tab anymore). You can find it in the **General** section in the left navigation below **Ratings and Reviews**

[image]

Or you create the URL this way:
`https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps/<app-id>/appstore/activity/ios/versions?m=`